# ODS graphics extremely slow (800x slower)

Tags: statistics, sas

The ODS graphics on option produces nicer graphics, but seems to take 800 fold longer than the base graphics. I've experienced this with a variety of different procedures. Platform is SAS 9.4 on windows 7.

Q1: Is this typical / expected? I could have sworn ODS graphics charts were being produced much faster on a colleague's machine last year.

Q2: How I can speed this up, right now I could manually create charts faster than ODS graphics. Also the base graphic charts are not professional looking enough, maybe if there were a way to export them as a decent png or svg format automatically with antialiased fonts? (bear in mind I'd like to write a program that creates thousands of charts automatically).

Q3: should I give up ODS graphics and switch back to traditional graphics?

Example below. If you execute this code and take a look at the execution times in the log, I'm seeing 0.09 seconds for the shewhart procedure with ODS graphics off and 1:13.11 seconds or even 1:20.23 seconds with ODS graphics on. If I additionally request html output, it could take longer than 2 minutes per chart.

```
/**********************************************************
Example illustrating ODS vs base graphics runtimes.
ODS takes orders of magnitude longer.
***********************************************************/
data jets;
input Engine Diam @@;
label Engine = "Engine Number";
datalines;
1 78.4 2 80.1 3 84.4 4 79.1 5 80.4
6 83.5 7 73.8 8 83.5 9 75.0 10 76.8
11 70.5 12 80.3 13 82.4 14 79.4 15 86.4
16 90.5 17 77.7 18 82.5 19 79.9 20 83.2
;

/**********************************************************
ODS Graphics off
***********************************************************/
ods graphics off;
title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
proc shewhart data=Jets;
irchart Diam*Engine;
run;

/**********************************************************
ODS Graphics on
***********************************************************/
ods graphics on;
title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
proc shewhart data=Jets;
irchart Diam*Engine;
run;

/**********************************************************
ODS Graphics on, ODS HTML
***********************************************************/
ods html file="irchart.html" path=gout style=STATISTICAL;
title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
proc shewhart data=Jets;
irchart Diam*Engine;
run;

ods html close;
ods graphics off;
```

And the log:

```
551  /**********************************************************
552  Example illustrating ODS vs base graphics runtimes.
553  ODS takes orders of magnitude longer.
554  ***********************************************************/
555  data jets;
556  input Engine Diam @@;
557  label Engine = "Engine Number";
558  datalines;

NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a
      line.
NOTE: The data set WORK.JETS has 20 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


563  ;
564
565  /**********************************************************
566  ODS Graphics off
567  ***********************************************************/
568  ods graphics off;
569  title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
570  title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
571  proc shewhart data=Jets;
572  irchart Diam*Engine;
573  run;

NOTE: Processing beginning for IRCHART statement number 1.
NOTE: Three-sigma limits are assumed.
NOTE: TYPE=ESTIMATE is assumed for the process mean and standard deviation used
      to compute the control limits.
NOTE: For process variable Diam moving ranges are based on 2 consecutive values.
NOTE: 48462 bytes written to C:\Users\carda10\sasgraph.svg.
NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.JETS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SHEWHART used (Total process time):
      real time           0.09 seconds
      cpu time            0.07 seconds


574
575  /**********************************************************
576  ODS Graphics on
577  ***********************************************************/
578  ods graphics on;
579  title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
580  title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
581  proc shewhart data=Jets;
582  irchart Diam*Engine;
583  run;

NOTE: Processing beginning for IRCHART statement number 1.
NOTE: Three-sigma limits are assumed.
NOTE: TYPE=ESTIMATE is assumed for the process mean and standard deviation used
      to compute the control limits.
NOTE: For process variable Diam moving ranges are based on 2 consecutive values.
NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.JETS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SHEWHART used (Total process time):
      real time           1:09.06
      cpu time            1.20 seconds


584
585  /**********************************************************
586  ODS Graphics on, ODS HTML
587  ***********************************************************/
588  ods html file="irchart.html" path=gout style=STATISTICAL;
NOTE: Writing HTML Body file: irchart.html
589  title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
590  title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
591  proc shewhart data=Jets;
592  irchart Diam*Engine;
593  run;

NOTE: Processing beginning for IRCHART statement number 1.
NOTE: Three-sigma limits are assumed.
NOTE: TYPE=ESTIMATE is assumed for the process mean and standard deviation used
      to compute the control limits.
NOTE: For process variable Diam moving ranges are based on 2 consecutive values.
NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.JETS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SHEWHART used (Total process time):
      real time           1:11.89
      cpu time            1.31 seconds


594
595  ods html close;
596  ods graphics off;
```

Update: I think this is related to printer (yes physical) access.

Comment: This is the type of question you should ask SAS Support to answer.

Comment: Try turning off view results as they are generated, under Preferences. If this is automated to generate 100's at a time, I doubt you're reviewing them manually.

Comment: I could ask SAS support, however I'm not sure anything out of the ordinary is going on.

Comment: They're still happy to help. Additionally you can post on communities.sas.com for some of the SAS developers to answer. The licensing fee has to be useful for something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was related to printer access.

I noticed that in other desktop applications, sometimes it took ~20 seconds to access the remote default printer.

Second, I also noticed that when I was on a network where the printer was reachable, it took much less time to generate each chart.

I then switched my default printer to a faux - adobe pdf generator. This brought down the chart generation time from 1-2 minutes to 0.09 seconds.

The effect is reproducible by switching back to the unreachable network printer and solved again by switching away from the network printer.

So it appears PROC SHEWHART and other operations are delayed and waiting to contact the network printer every time a chart is to be generated, even if it's not going to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

I could not replicate your results, running 9.4 on Linux server.

Sometimes ODS graphics do feel slow to me, but it's more like a half second per graph slow, not 10 seconds or  2 minutes.  I think @Reeza's suggestion to try tech support is a good one.

I see in your update that you closing all ODS destinations helped.  Certainly if you had multiple destinations open, perhaps requiring different image formats, that would slow things down.  But 2 minutes still seems out-of-bounds for one simple chart.

My log is:

```
22         /**********************************************************
23         ODS Graphics off
24         ***********************************************************/
25         ods graphics off;
26         title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
27         title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
28         proc shewhart data=Jets;
29         irchart Diam*Engine;
30         run;

NOTE: Processing beginning for IRCHART statement number 1.
NOTE: Three-sigma limits are assumed.
NOTE: TYPE=ESTIMATE is assumed for the process mean and standard deviation used to compute the control limits.
NOTE: For process variable Diam moving ranges are based on 2 consecutive values.
NOTE: 33382 bytes written to /sas/saswork/.../shewhar5.png.
NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.JETS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SHEWHART used (Total process time):
      real time           0.16 seconds
      cpu time            0.16 seconds


31         
32         /**********************************************************
33         ODS Graphics on
34         ***********************************************************/
35         ods graphics on;
36         title 'Individual Measurements and Moving Range Charts';
37         title2 'Jet Engine Diameters (cm)';
38         proc shewhart data=Jets;
39         irchart Diam*Engine;
40         run;

NOTE: Processing beginning for IRCHART statement number 1.
NOTE: Three-sigma limits are assumed.
NOTE: TYPE=ESTIMATE is assumed for the process mean and standard deviation used to compute the control limits.
NOTE: For process variable Diam moving ranges are based on 2 consecutive values.
NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.JETS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SHEWHART used (Total process time):
      real time           0.23 seconds
      cpu time            0.08 seconds
```